# Rails 4: Looping through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I am having some trouble while looping some association:

```
#=> member.rb
has_one :academic

#=> academic.rb
belongs_to :member
```

So far so good. However, when I loop through the association, I get:

`undefined method 'each' for #<Academic:0x007fc98b2b7210>`

Here's my view (show):

```
<% if !@member.academic.nil? %>
 <% fields_academic = [:major, :second_major, :minor, :second_minor] %>

  <h1>Academics</h1>

  <% @member.academic.each do |academic| %>
 <%= render 'database/shared/display', model_obj: academic, data: academic, fields: fields_academic %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The code is stuck at the `each` method.

`@member` is defined as `= Member.find(params[:id])`

Any help will be gladly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code there are no multiple instances of `academic` related to the given `member` (it's defined using `has_one` relation).

The answer is: you cannot loop them.

The correct code for your view should be:

```
<% if @member.academic.present? %>
 <% fields_academic = [:major, :second_major, :minor, :second_minor] %>
  <h1>Academics</h1>
  <%= render 'database/shared/display', model_obj: @memeber.academic, data: academic, fields: fields_academic %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If your intention was to have many academics for a memeber, then use `has_many` instead.

```
class Member
  has_many :academics
end
```

Comment: I am getting `undefined method 'major' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` when I try to show in my index table.

Answer (score 2):

`each` should be used on a ***collection of records***( I mean which results in a multiple records). Currently `@member.academic` will return a ***single record*** as it is a `has_one` relation between `member` and `academic`, so you can't loop with that. May be you should change your association to `has_many :academics` and loop it like `<% @member.academics.each do |academic| %>`

Comment: I am getting `undefined method 'major' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` when I try to show in my index table.

Comment: @ViniciusMartinson Ask another question explaining your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Method :each iterates over the block according to how this Enumerable was constructed. If no block is given, returns self. Enumerable is a mixin that provides to collections some useful methods. In your example `academic` is a not Enumerable, but single object. You should use `has_many` association.

Comment: I am getting `undefined method 'major' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` when I try to show in my index table.

Comment: If I understood you correct, 'major' is a your model field. In lazy-loading collections you can't call model field direct. I think, you should read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html